# Javascript convert NaN string attribute to usable number

Tags: javascript, parsing, svg, types, nan

Here is the problem,

Somewhere in my project, I have a svg container, on which I have to apply transformations.
Transformations are just a "text attribute", so, I calculate a value and then set it as my svg attribute.

The value I get is a "scale" value. It goes from 0.1 to 1+(0.x) with max 2 value. Example, here is the value i get :

```
var scaleValue = "1.3000";
```

I put it as "transform" attribute this way :

```
myItem.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","scale("+scaleValue+")");
```

So now, the svg item has an attribute called "transform" which contains a scale with a value.

Later in my code, i need to get this value back! and now come the troubles...
I get the value back this way :

```
var transformString = myItem.getAttribute("transform");
var scale = transformString.substr((transformString.indexOf('(',transformString.indexOf(('scale('),0))+1),(transformString.indexOf((')',transformString.indexOf('scale(')))-1));
console.log(scale);
```

Console.log(scale) gives me 1.3000... So, the value i get is the good one, BUT i get it as a string (I'm parsing a string...)

Then I need to do some stuff with this value, like, on mouseEvent :

```
var currentPositionX = (event.offsetX==undefined?event.layerX:event.offsetX)*scale;
```

So, at this point, i need the scale to be a "float" or something I can use to calculate values... and each time i try to do this, i get this message :

```
Unexpected NaN value ...
```

UPDATE :

seems the problem comes from the calculations i have to do.
So, first one is get the mouse offset :

```
var offsetX = event.offsetX==undefined?event.layerX:event.offsetX;
```

this gives me a value like "2048", i output it in console like this for example :

```
console.log(parseFloat(offsetX));
```

and I get the right value displayed.
Later i try this :

```
var calculated = (parseFloat(offsetX))*(parseFloat(scale));
```

and THERE, when i output the result like this :

```
console.log(calculated);
```

i get "NaN"...

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) it after you fetch it as a string:

```
scale = parseFloat(scale);
```

Comment: i did it... when i console.log(parseFloat(scale)) i get 1.3 in console, but seems the problem comes from the calculation i'm doing with offset values...

Comment: But what's the problem then? You said `Console.log(scale) gives me 1.3000... So, the value i get is the good one, BUT i get it as a string (I'm parsing a string...)`.

Comment: console.log(typeof(offsetX)) gives me "number" and console.log(typeof(scale)) gives me "object"... Here is the problem...

Comment: Okay, one last thing, what is the value of the `scale` object?

Comment: value of "scale" is the string "1.x" (1.3, or whatever...), parseFloat(scale) is a "number"... (offsetXValue) is a number too... :/ but using these 2 vars in the same calculation gives "NaN" return...

Comment: Something's wrong here, you said the typeof scale is an object, not a string. Are there two different scale variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65130/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-shomz).